# Error while using listagg in oracle "STRING concatenation too long"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, listagg

I have a table like temp_a which has:

```
acc ai_tab   where
A   B        QQQQ
A   B        RRRR
C   D        SSSS
C   D        TTTT
```

The column `where` has too large string stored. so,My expected output is

```
acc ai_tab where 
A   B      QQQQ RRRR
C   D      SSSS TTTT
```

I tried to achieve this using:

```
 select acc,ai_tab,LISTAGG(WHERE,'') WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY (acc) "where_cond2" from temp_a
group by acc,ai_tab;
```

I got the error as:

```
ORA-01489 :result of string concatenation is too long.
```

I searched this similar question and its says use the XMLCLOB also but its not working?Can we use function to get this or is there any other methods?

Comment: If you're on 12cR2 you could use the overflow option to handle the problem gracefully. It truncates the output but at least your query doesn't throw an error. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/listagg-function-enhancements-12cr2#handling-overflow-errors). When you say *"XMLCLOB [is] not working"* what happens? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: but i should not need to truncate the data . I need all the values of those string

Comment: can u helo me by showing th eexmaple @APC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Littlefoot's solution. 
Alternatively, you could perhaps write your own function. I've included a sample below.
Note: I haven't tested this with your data, so not sure how well this would perform

```
    SQL> create table foo as
         select 'A' acc, 'B' ai_tab, 'QQQQ' where_column from dual union all
         select 'A','B','RRRR' from dual union all
         select 'C','D','SSSS' from dual union all
         select 'C','D','TTTT' from dual;

    Table created.

    SQL> select * from foo;

    ACC AI_TAB WHERE_COLUMN
    --  --     ----
    A   B      QQQQ
    A   B      RRRR
    C   D      SSSS
    C   D      TTTT

    SQL> create or replace function str_concat (
             p_acc       in  foo.acc%type,
             p_ai_tab    in  foo.ai_tab%type
             )
         return clob
         is
             l_concat  clob;
         begin
         for o in ( 
                 select where_column from foo where acc = p_acc and ai_tab =  p_ai_tab  
             ) loop
                     l_concat := l_concat || ' ' || o.where_column;
                 end loop;
             return ltrim(l_concat, ' ');
         end;
         /

    Function created.

    SQL> select acc, ai_tab, where_column from (
         select acc, ai_tab, str_concat(acc, ai_tab) where_column, row_number() over (partition by acc, ai_tab order by null)
         ) where rn = 1;

    ACC AI_TAB  WHERE_COLUMN
    --  --      ----
    A   B       QQQQ RRRR
    C   D       SSSS TTTT
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example which shows both options you might use; as `listagg` fails, try `xmlagg` instead.

```
SQL> SELECT RTRIM (
  2            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, ename || ' ') ORDER BY empno).EXTRACT (
  3               '//text()'),
  4            ', ')
  5            employees_1,
  6         --
  7         LISTAGG (ename, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY empno) employees_2
  8    FROM emp
  9   WHERE deptno = 10;

EMPLOYEES_1                    EMPLOYEES_2
------------------------------ ------------------------------
CLARK KING MILLER              CLARK KING MILLER

SQL>
```

Comment: i dont need comma i need space

Comment: What prevents you to replace comma with space?

Comment: i replace but all values are coming null

Comment: all my data inside ' ' is coming as &apos.why it is coming like that?

Comment: Everything works OK for me; I modified example to separate strings with a space. As of your another problem: is sample data really what you posted, or something else?

Comment: no its jsut dummy data real data looks like this coloumn1-> where a.payer='a'  column2 -> where a.payer='b'

Comment: the string wrapped inside '' is coimng as where a.payer=&apos;a;&apos. Why my '' is replaced by such codes?

Comment: Which tool do you use while running that query?

Comment: i am using sqltools

Comment: Hm, I don't know what it is, sorry. Maybe it causes your problems because - it works as expected in SQL*Plus (which I copy/pasted), SQL Developer and TOAD

Comment: its shwoing character string buffer too small now i have as same u have done above

Comment: Are you storing result of the XMLAGG into some variable? If so, what is its size?